# Strange matlab performance when using editor against command window

Tags: performance, matlab, performance-testing

I might have misunderstood something.. but I expected the running of a code in the editor and in the command window to be the same..

I have the following code in the editor

```
display('  ');
display('script');
fac = @(n) prod(1:n);

n=20;
display(['- use of anonymous function: fac = @(n) prod(1:n); with n = ' num2str(n)]);
tic; fac(n); toc;

display(['- use of build in MatLab function: factorial(); with n = ' num2str(n)]);
tic; factorial(n); toc;
```

before I run (is that called compiled or execute?) I quickly type in the same command in the command window. Which gives me this:

[image: strange performance time]

So all of a sudden the factorial function in the editor got a boost when it comes to performance.. What just happened?

Comment: Definitely an interesting question. See also the performance difference between `tic; fac(n); toc;tic; factorial(n); toc;` and `tic; factorial(n); toc;tic; fac(n); toc;` in the command line. The order of function calls seems to make a difference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the calculation you are trying to measure is too quick to get anything like an accurate reading. It is way below the measurement noise you get when using tic/toc because of other processes and activity on the system. To get more accurate measures repeat the calculation many times... (I would repeat the calculation so it takes 10-20 seconds).

Second, there is indeed a difference between code typed interactively and in a script. I think the JIT only runs for code run from a script or function m-file, where and not for stuff running in the interpreter (but I am struggling to find a reference for this now - I will add if I find it).

Answer (score 1):

you mean the differences in running time between running in command window and running from script? I think they're caused by everything else also running on your computer, matlab's own memory management and a few other things...

it is explained in greater detail here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/296850

Another method of measuring the time spent on cpu is the function [cputime](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/cputime.html). It has however lower precision. So expand your test case in that it takes a longer time (<s>n=2e7 eg</s> factorial is capped at 171) to see results with cputime.

Conclusion: one swallow does not a summer make

Extend your testing with more cases.

```
n=200;
tic;
for ii=1:1e4
    factorial(n);
end;
toc
```